# How can I check if a command was succesful or not?

Tags: python, subprocess

So, I'm trying to check if the command was successful or not when doing subprocess command.

I'm really bad at explaining but just look at my example:

Here's my code

```
output = subprocess.getoutput("sdf")
print(output)
```

I want to check if the output is:

```
'sdf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried this code:

```
error_temp = fr"'sdf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
if output == error_temp:
   print("'sdf' was not recognized by this system, please register this command and try again later.")
else:
   print(output)
```

But it's not really working, I think it's got to do with a skip line in the output...

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:**

I fixed this problem thanks to @Cristian

Here's my updated code:

```
status = subprocess.getstatusoutput("sdf")
print(status[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [getstatusoutput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getstatusoutput) function from the same package. It returns a tuple with the exit code and the message. If the exit code is 0, it is considered as a successful completion. Other codes indicate an abnormal completion.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to show an alternative to `getstatusoutput`, an older method that always launches a shell to execute your program, which may be inefficient if you do not need the facilities that a shell provides (such as wildcard expansion).

The following uses [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) (which can also use a shell to execute your program if you specify `shell=True`). The first example does not capture the output from the executed program and the second example does. The program being run is a small Python program, `test.py`, executed with the command `python test.py`

**test.py**

```
print('It works.\n')
```

**Example 1 -- Do not capture output**

```
import subprocess


completed_process = subprocess.run(['python', 'test.py'])
print(completed_process.returncode)
```

Prints:

```
It works.
0
```

**Example 2 -- Capture output**

```
import subprocess


completed_process = subprocess.run(['python', 'test.py'], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(completed_process.returncode)
print(completed_process.stdout)
```

Prints:

```
0
It works.
```

Comment: Thanks! I might consider switching to this method! I found out that `subprocess.getoutput` doesn't work with the `cd` command, so I'm just wondering if `subprocess.run` does?

Comment: For that you should use the `os.chdir` function because even with `subprocess.run` after it returns you will be back in the original directory.